# Parsing through output

Tags: python, bash, parsing

I would like to create a list of Virtual IP values. There could one or more Virtual addresses associated with an interface. (192.168.1.1,192.168.2.1,192.168.3.1)

```
[Switch] disp vrrp verbose interface Vlan-interface 1 | begin Virtual_IP
     Virtual IP     : 192.168.1.1
                      192.168.2.1
     Master IP      : 0.0.0.0
     VRName         :
     Follow Name 

[Switch] disp vrrp verbose interface Vlan-interface2 | begin Virtual_IP
     Virtual IP     : 192.168.3.1
     Master IP      : 0.0.0.0
     VRName         :
     Follow Name    :
```

What I tried is to first, split the output using .split function and string "Master" as delimiter. Then I would use the first list item and spitted again using ":" as delimiter. The 2nd list item now contains:

192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1

When I split it again now using \n as delimeter I receive three items
192.168.1.1 192.168.2.1 and empty tab or white space

I could perhaps iterate through this last list and "remove" empty spaces, new lines and tabs.

Is this good approach is there a better way how to get same results?

Comment: What did you try and where does it fail? Please provide your [mcve] with a specific problem. SO is no free coding service.

Comment: Thanks, I tried few things, getting to the point, I have rewritten the original question.

Answer (score 0):

this script work the job. in this example the text is in the test file:

```
ip=$(grep '192.168' ./test | tr -d "Virtual IP\:")
echo $ip
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the IP address can by from any range. However I have managed to further reduce the output from source command

display vrrp verbose interface Vlan-interface 1 | begin Virtual_IP

Which resulted in 

     Virtual IP     : 192.168.1.1
                      192.168.2.1
     Master IP      : 0.0.0.0
     VRName         :
     Follow Name 

I am investigating whether I could use re library in python to parse it through and finally have a list of these VIPs as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using different approach. First capturing the whole command output without piping it on the device itself.

```
output = connection.send_command('display vrrp verbose interface vlan-interface1')
```

Then using splitlines() with range, I extracted the "interesting" lines.

```
lines = output.splitlines()[10:-3]
```

Then it was a matter splitting each line into words and checking the contents of them, there are were two possibilities for match, either there was only one 1 word:

```
words = line.split()

    if len(words) == 1:
        #If only single word is returned then it is a VIP
        print('Words is equal to 1')
        vip = words[0]
        vips.append(vip)
```

or there more with 2nd item containing the string 'IP'

```
 elif words[1] == 'IP':
    #If multiple words are returned the 2nd will contain
    #IP vs MAC string
    print('Words Item 2 is qual to IP')
    vip = words[-1]
    vips.append(vip)
```

As a result vips list will contain all VIPs, one or more.